# Python multiprocessing: process a list of input files with error logging

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing, error-logging

I want to use python multiprocessing to conduct the following:

- process a long list of input files
- include error logging
- set a limit on the concurrent CPU cores in use (number of processes)

The [python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) has two excellent examples for multiprocessing. In the code below, I've modified the second method ("logging in the main process, in a separate thread") which uses multiprocessing.Queue. Both for myself and new users, I have added detailed notes, and created example input and output files.

Where I'm stuck is that the code iterates through the number of CPU cores, NOT through the number of items in my list.

How can I apply the function to all my input files, without exceeding the limit on the number of concurrent processes?

```
import json
import logging
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

def create_10_infiles():
    """Creates 10 csv files with 4x4 array of floats, + occasional strings"""
    list_csv_in = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        csv_in = "{:02d}_in.csv".format(i)
        # create a 4 row, 4 column dataframe with random values centered around i
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(16).reshape(4,4) * i)
        # add a string to one of the arrays (as a reason to need error logging)
        if i == 2 or i == 8:
            df.loc[2,2] = "Oops, array contains a string. Welcome to data science."
        # save to csv, and append filename to list of inputfiles
        df.to_csv(csv_in)
        list_csv_in.append(csv_in)
    return list_csv_in

def logger_thread(queue):
    """Listener process that logs output received from other processes?"""
    while True:
        record = queue.get()
        if record is None:
            break
        logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
        logger.handle(record)

def worker_process(queue, infile):
    """Worker process that used to run tasks.
    Each process is isolated, so it starts by setting up logging."""
    # set up a handle to hold the logger output?
    queue_handle = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)
    # creates a new logger called "process logger" (printed in each line)
    logger = logging.getLogger("process logger")
    # sets the logging level to DEBUG, so logger.info messages are printed.
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # connects logger to handle defined above?
    logger.addHandler(queue_handle)
    # here you can run your desired program, in the hope that the time saved from parallel
    # processing is greater than the overhead of setting up all those processes and loggers:)
    normalise_array_to_mean_and_save(infile, logger)

def normalise_array_to_mean_and_save(csv_in, logger):
    """Opens csv with array, checks dtypes, calculates mean, saves output csv."""
    # check if file exists
    if os.path.isfile(csv_in):
        # open as pandas dataframe
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_in)
        # if none of the columns contain mixed datatypes (i.e, a string)
        if not pd.np.dtype('object') in df.dtypes.tolist():
            # calc mean over whole dataframe
            mean = df.stack().mean()
            logger.info("{}, Mean = {:0.2f}".format(csv_in, mean))
            # normalise all values to mean. Save as "01_out.csv", "02_out.csv" etc
            df = df / mean
            csv_out = csv_in[:-6] + "out.csv"
            df.to_csv(csv_out)
        else:
            logger.info("{}, Mean not calculated. Non-float values found.".format(csv_in))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir(r"D:\data")
    # import your favourite json logging settings (collapsed for brevity)
    logsettings = json.dumps({"version": 1, "root": {"handlers": ["console", "file"], "level": "DEBUG"}, "formatters": {"detailed": {"class": "logging.Formatter", "format": "%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(processName)-10s %(message)s"}}, "handlers": {"console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "level": "DEBUG"}, "file": {"mode": "w", "formatter": "detailed", "class": "logging.FileHandler", "filename": "my_multiprocessing_logfile.log"}}})
    config = json.loads(logsettings)
    # replace default logfile with a filename containing the exact time
    config['handlers']['file']['filename'] = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S") + "_mp_logfile.txt"
    # load the logging settings
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    workers = []
    # set the number of concurrent processes created (i.e. CPU cores used)
    num_processes = 4

    # create 10 csv files with data, and return the list of filepaths
    list_10_infiles = create_10_infiles()

    # set up a process for each CPU core (e.g. 4)
    for i in range(num_processes):
        wp = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process,
                                     name='worker_{}'.format(i+1),
                                     args=(queue, list_10_infiles[i]))
        workers.append(wp)
        wp.start()

    # set up a thread as the logger_process
    logger_process = threading.Thread(target=logger_thread, args=(queue,))
    logger_process.start()

    #At this point, the main process could do some useful work of its own
    #Once it's done that, it can wait for the workers to terminate...
    for wp in workers:
        wp.join()

    # set logger for main process if desired
    root = logging.getLogger("main")
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger("main logger")
    logger.info("CPUs used = {}/{}".format(num_processes, multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    logger.info('Program is finished. All files analysed.')

    # And now tell the logging thread to finish up, too
    queue.put(None)
    logger_process.join()
```

Note: I've tried dividing the list of input files into chunks depending on the number of CPU cores. This processed the files, but was very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using python multiprocessing Pool instead of Queue allowed me to process a long list of files, and limit the number of concurrent cores.

Although logging is not compatible with Pool, I found that it is possible to collect the return values. The return values can be logged after all files have been processed, assuming the code doesn't throw an exception.

Maybe someone here can give me a more elegant solution, but for the moment this solves the problem.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import strftime
import logging

def function_to_process_files(file):
    #..check file integrity, etc..
    if file_gives_an_error:
        return "{} file {} gave an error".format(strftime("%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S"), file)
    #..do stuff without using the logging module..
    #.. for slow, irregular processes, printing to console is possible..
    return "{} file {} processed correctly".format(strftime("%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S"), file)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    list_of_files_to_process = define_your_file_list_somehow()

    logging = logging.setup_regular_logging_to_file_as_desired()

    # define the number of CPU cores to be used concurrently
    n_processes = 4

    with Pool(processes=n_processes) as pool:
        list_of_return_statements = pool.map(function_to_process_files, list_of_files_to_process)
    # now transfer the list of return statements to the logfile
    for return_statement in list_of_return_statements:
        logging.info(return_statement)
```